# How to do products sorting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting

I need to make a food ordering site for a university graduation project and I have no previous experience in the subject. I did most of the site, but I want to sort with the blue buttons in the menu, but I couldn't do it. I created @Html.ActionLink Name and Price links to try it but it doesn't work. That's why I couldn't assign tasks to the blue buttons. Alphabetically, best seller, price ascending, price descending. Can you help me?

Controller

````
```

public class MenuController : Controller
{
    // GET: Menu
    Context c = new Context();
    public ActionResult Index(string sortBy)
    {
        ViewBag.SortNameParameter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) ? "Name desc" : "";
        ViewBag.SortPriceParameter = sortBy == "Price" ? "Price desc" : "Price";

        var uruns = c.Uruns.AsQueryable();

        switch(sortBy)
        {
            case "Name desc":
                uruns = uruns.OrderByDescending(x => x.UrunAdi);
                break;
            case "Price desc":
                uruns = uruns.OrderByDescending(x => x.UrunFiyat);
                break;
            case "Price":
                uruns = uruns.OrderBy(x => x.UrunFiyat);
                break;
            default:
                uruns = uruns.OrderBy(x => x.UrunAdi);
                break;
        }

   
        Context _db = new Context();
        Menu vm = new Menu();
        //vm.Deger1 = (_db.Uruns.Where(i=>i.Durum)&&_db.Kategoris.Where(i=>i.Durum)).ToList();
        vm.Deger1 = _db.Uruns.Where(i=>i.Durum).ToList();
        vm.Deger2 = _db.Kategoris.Where(i=>i.Durum).ToList();

        return View(vm);
    }
````

```
View
```

```
    <ul class="filters_menu">
        <li class="active" data-filter="*">All</li>
        @foreach (var k in Model.Deger2)

        {
            if (k.Durum != false)
            {
                <li class="" data-filter=".@k.KategoriAdi">@k.KategoriAdi</li>
            }
        }

    </ul>
    <p class="filters_menu">

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-round" type="button">A/Z</button>&nbsp;
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-round" type="button">En çok satan</button>&nbsp;
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-round" type="button">Fiyat (Artan)</button>&nbsp;
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-round" type="button">Fiyat (Azalan)</button>&nbsp;
        @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { sortBy = ViewBag.SortNameParameter })
        @Html.ActionLink("Price", "Index", new { sortBy = ViewBag.SortPriceParameter })
    </p>
    <div class="filters-content">
        <div class="row grid">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Deger1.OrderBy(item => item.UrunFiyat))
            {
                //if (item. != false)
                //{
                using (Html.BeginForm("SepeteEkle", "Sepet", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = item.Urunid }))
                {
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 all @item.Kategori.KategoriAdi">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div>
                                <div class="img-box">
                                    <img src="@item.UrunGorsel" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="detail-box">
                                    <h5>
                                        @item.UrunAdi
                                    </h5>
                                    <div class="options">
                                        <h6>
                                            @item.UrunFiyat ₺
                                        </h6>
                                        <input name="Id" value="@item.Urunid" type="hidden" />
                                        <input name="qty" class="form-control" type="number" name="" value="1" max="10" min="1" style="max-width: 60px; min-width: 60px;" />
                                        <input type="submit" value="Sepete Ekle" class="btn btn-success btn-circle" />
                                        @*<button class="btn btn-success btn-circle" type="button">Sepete Ekle</button>*@
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
[Menu][1]

[1] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1SVO.jpg

Comment: In your code, you are sorting "uruns", but then you ignore it and get new lists from the db

Comment: I did something like that to be able to use 2 different models in one view. I don't know how to fix it can you help me?

Comment: Maybe replace _db.Uruns with just uruns where you assign vm.Deger1?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I didn't realize I was creating a new list. That's how I did it to be able to use category and product models in a view. Thanks to your warning, I realized that I was being silly, took the category bar to partialview, used the product as a single model and listed the sorting I made and my problem was solved.